# navigator.share is working on mobile but not working on laptop

Tags: javascript

navigator.share is working on mobile but not working on laptop windows and ios as well
on chrome and on safari its not working

navigator.canShare({files: [file]}) returns true and also it's opening the popup of sharing but showing only loader and its dis appear

```
if(navigator.share && navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare({
     files: [file] 
   })) {
     await navigator.share({
        title: "",
        text: "",
        url: "",
        files: [file] 
     })
     .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
     .catch((error) => console.log('Error in sharing', error));
   }else {
      console.log(`system does not support sharing files.`);
   }
```

and in console it's printing 'Successful share'

Comment: "is working on mobile but not working on laptop windows and ios as well on chrome and on safari its not working" — This is a really hard sentence to parse. Please clearly list the browser + operating system combinations you have tested this with along which which did and didn't work.

Comment: @Quentin i have checked on windows with chrome Version 92.0.4515.159
and on edge Version 92.0.902.84

Comment: on both (windows with chrome Version 92.0.4515.159 and on edge Version 92.0.902.84 ) it's not working but when i was checked on mobile android 11 and chrome version 92.0.4515.131 it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

Please note: [According to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share), The `navigator.share` API is only compatible with the following **browser** versions and **OS**,

**Computers**

- **Edge 81**
- **Safari 12.1** (MacOS)
- **Chrome 89** (Not on MacOS)

**Mobile Devices**

- **Chrome 61** (Android)
- **Opera 48** (Android)
- **Safari 12.2** (iOS)
- **Samsung Internet** (Android)

So, Make sure you test it on compatible **Browser** and **OS** combination.

Comment: I have checked on latest version of chrome and edge 
i have checked on windows with chrome Version 92.0.4515.159 and on edge Version 92.0.902.84